# Why two hexadecimal digit can only stand 8 bits in MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

This is one of my network adapter, the MAC address is: `a0:99:9b:17:52:07`:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a0:99:9b:17:52:07 
    inet6 fe80::c48:cc97:a24d:e029%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.106 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

we know the MAC address is 48 bits = 6 Bytes.

but in the `a0:99:9b:17:50:07`, we know hexadecimal digits is from `0` to `f`. the `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` each `xx` can from `00` to `ff` range, why say `xx` can only stand 8 bits?

---

**EDIT-01**

Because the `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` stands for 48 bits, so the `xx` stand `8` bits. the `xx` is from `00` to `ff` range, so why `xx` can only stand 8 bit?

Comment: Please quote the article claiming that two hexadecimal characters stand for 8 bits, without that, this question is not making much sense. In anyway, two hexadecimal characters stand for 16 bits, 8 bits per character.

Comment: @Teun ... I'm sure the question meant precisely hex digit; not how much space it might take to write in ASCII or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hexadecimal digit can have sixteen different values, 0..9 and A..F, representing 0..15 in decimal.

For the same value in binary you need four bits, 0000..1111, representing the same 2<sup>4</sup> values. Two of those four-bit nibbles or hexadecimal digits form a byte, representing 16*16 = 256 values.

48 bits or six bytes require 12 hex digits, often written with - or : in between (byte) pairs.

Comment: ... and occasionally written with '.' between groups of four digits, as on Cisco equipment: `649e.f312.3456` which is the same as `64:9e:f3:12:34:56`

Answer (score -2):

because you need 4 bits to calculate an hex degit for example

1101 = 13 in decimal and "d" in hexadecimal so every 4 bit represents an hex degit in a mac address